# C++ put a struct in shared memory

Tags: c++, shared-memory

I want to write a chat room program of C++, and I will use `fork()` after `accept()`,
all of the clients will communicate by shared memory, the following is part of my code,
I put a struct in shared memory, but i get compile error.
How can I fix it, or someone can give me an example, thanks!

```c
typedef struct ClientList{
int pid[30];
int whoid[30];
string name[30];
bool online[30];
string ip[30];
int port[30];
string file[30][30];
int pid_who[30][30];
int onlineUser;
}ClientList;


/*Shared memory*/
int segment_id;
ClientList shared_memory;
struct shmid_ds shmbuffer;
int segment_size;
const int shared_segment_size = sizeof(shared_memory);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* Allocate a shared memory segment. */
    segment_id = shmget (IPC_PRIVATE, shared_segment_size, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    /* Attach the shared memory segment. */
    shared_memory = (ClientList) shmat (segment_id, 0, 0);
    printf ("shared memory attached at address %p\n", shared_memory);

    /* Determine the segment’s size. */
    shmctl (segment_id, IPC_STAT, &shmbuffer);
    segment_size = shmbuffer.shm_segsz;
    printf ("segment size: %d\n", segment_size);
}
```

The error message is
`pipe.cpp: In function 「int main(int, char**)」:` 
`pipe.cpp:57:55: 錯誤：對 「ClientList::ClientList(void*)」 的呼叫沒有匹配的函式`
`pipe.cpp:57:55: 附註：candidates are:`
`pipe.cpp:31:16: 附註：ClientList::ClientList()`
`pipe.cpp:31:16: 附註：  candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided`
`pipe.cpp:31:16: 附註：ClientList::ClientList(const ClientList&)`
`pipe.cpp:31:16: 附註：  no known conversion for argument 1 from 「void*」 to 「const ClientList&」`
`pipe.cpp:58:66: 錯誤：cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 「ClientList {aka struct ClientList}」 through 「...」`

Comment: IMHO, it's not good idea to use `std::string` in shared memory.

Comment: @hate-engine oh, thanks for your advise, the reason seems that the dynamic allocate problem? I will change `std:string` to fixed size char array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pointer, not value

```
ClientList* shared_memory;
     here ^

shared_memory = (ClientList* ) shmat (segment_id, 0, 0);
                  and here ^
```

Ah, and then your sizeof will look like this

```
const int shared_segment_size = sizeof(ClientList);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still have a compile error, it shows `no match for 「operator=」 in 「shared_memory = (ClientList*)shmat(segment_id, 0u, 0)」`

Comment: @ChengChung-Hao, you need to declare `shared_memory` as a pointer as well, see updated answer

Comment: C-style casts, though perfectly legal in C++, are considered bad programming style. Try `shared_memory = reintepret_cast<ClientList*> (shmat (segment_id, 0, 0)); ` Or, more C++ way, use a placement new: `shared_memory = new (shmat (segment_id, 0, 0)) ClientList;`